# Unresolved reference: lifecycle_version [developer.android.com/codelabs]

Tags: android

Code available here:

Starter code URL:

https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-dessert-clicker

Branch name with starter code: main

---

Instructions in codelab: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-test-viewmodel?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-4-pathway-1%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-test-viewmodel#3

```
    Add the following variable to your project build.gradle file:
```

```kotlin
buildscript {
   ext {
       ...
       lifecycle_version = '2.5.1'
   }
}
```

however, adding this to `build.gradle.kts` (Project) leads to error:

```
Unresolved reference: lifecycle_version
```

Moreover,

```
buildscript {
    ext {
```

is not there, I've to manually define it and populate it with `lifecycle_version`, whereas in the codelab it exemplifies as if it's already there.

Anybody who has done the codelab and has a clue on how to proceed forward? I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I added

```kotlin
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.1")
```

to build.gradle.kts (app).